# How can I use <md-progress-circular> on <ng-click>?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

.html

```
<md-button class="btn btn-primary text-center center-block" type="submit" style="padding: 6px 100px"
ng-click="showSpinner = !showSpinner" class="btn btn-default btn-sm view-mode pull-left" my-click-once keep-width>

 <span ng-show="!showSpinner">Demo of the circular spinner in md-button</span>

 <md-progress-circular ng-show="showSpinner" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>

</md-button>
```

.js

```
//Directive for progress spinner
app.directive('keepWidth', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      var width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
      var otherCss = element.css('cssText');

      attrs.$set('style', 'width: ' + width + 'px;' + otherCss);
    }
  }
});
```

Above is my code, I just want to show the progress spinner on click. I am using angular 1.5.0 because I have to.

When I press the button, it shrinks and removes the text and that is all.

I am using this https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ as reference. I was told these are the materials for angularJS 1 (which I assume includes 1.5.0)

What am I doing wrong? Are my materials incorrect? Not sure if angularJS 1can use md-progress-circular, but those materials suggest otherwise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Place the `md-progress` outside your md-button. Also, use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`.

```
<md-button class="btn btn-primary text-center center-block" type="submit" style="padding: 6px 100px" ng-click="showSpinner = !showSpinner" class="btn btn-default btn-sm view-mode pull-left" my-click-once keep-width>

 <span ng-show="!showSpinner">Demo of the circular spinner in md-button</span>

</md-button>
<md-progress-circular ng-if="showSpinner" mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
```

Comment: Still does the same. Could it be the version of angular?

Comment: What if you use `mode="indeterminate"` instead of `md-mode` ?